# Need help with my 2006 Saab 9-7x

Tags: electrical

My 2006 Saab 97x starts then stalls. I plugged in the OBDII reader and one of the codes is P0601 (Internal Control Module Memory Check Sum Error). How do I fix this?

Comment: Does the fault code reappear after clearing the codes, cycling the ignition and rescanning?  Have you tried to scan it with multiple scanners?

Comment: what module do you get P0601 in the engine ecu or another?

Answer (score 0):

Your ecu is either knackered(rare) or more likely, an earth cable is failing or loose-check all earth wires.

Comment: How does this answer even start to explain to the OP how to fix their issue? We are looking for answers which can actually help people. How would the OP go about figuring out if either of these "issues" you state are the actual problems with their vehicle? Instead of just throwing down useless one liners in your answers, please consider paying a little attention to how the OP might go about *fixing* their issue.

Comment: I have identified 2 possible reasons-therefore, given a direction to go to first. I am not just chucking down answers, but have had experience on a similar saab with this issue. Note the phrase ‘check’ earths, which is indeed, a suggestion how to fix the issue. If this fails, then next would be to check the ecu

Answer (score 0):

Checksum errors are usually from corrupted flash/eeprom area's in the module in questions. Sometimes you can re-flash them to fix the problem. Any shop with a j2534 tool can re-flash it using GM SPS ($120-$150).  The engine computer (I am assuming your issue is with) is not that expensive used ($50-$100) so you may be better off to just have them flash a replacement instead in case the original is faulty and not just corrupted. The 9-7 saabs are not quite the pain to work on as their older models but you may still run into some resistance from shops when you mention its a Saab.